# How to use the like button with a php application using facebook api?

Tags: php, api, facebook, facebook-like

I have a facebook application in my website. When someone is already logged in to my website, I have the `offline_access` of his facebook account, but when I put a like button, it always asks for login to facebook again.

Everything else works, like printing the posts, photos, etc. But the simple action of liking something, doesn't. How can I make it work using the php-sdk api?

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that you have just used the like button code from [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/web/). What's happening when they click that button it's not going THROUGH your website but rather taking a bit with it to facebook. So it takes your URL to facebook and they do the whole posting bit... therefore if the client is not logged into facebook it'll ask them to login.

What you can do is use a curl posting script through your website and that should post whether they are logged into the facebook main site or not provided they logged in with the offline_access.

Please tell me if you need more information or if I have mis-interpreted what you meant.

Regards,

Jon

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are misunderstanding the behavior of the `offline_access` permission:

> Enables your application to perform
>   authorized requests on behalf of the
>   user at any time. By default, most
>   access tokens expire after a short
>   time period to ensure applications
>   only make requests on behalf of the
>   user when the are actively using the
>   application. This permission makes the
>   access token returned by our OAuth
>   endpoint long-lived.

This would mean, even if the user is logged off, your application will still have access to it's account BUT this DOES NOT mean that you can capture/monitor if the user is back on your website again until he is logged to his FB account again.
So `offline_access` will **never** know if the same user is currently on the page and "*automatically*" log him to his FB account!